# Scrolling a tree node to top of a scroll pane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtree

I have a [`JTree`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html) with about more than 8 tree nodes(leafs). The requirement is if user clicks on a tree node, the selected tree node will automatically scrolls to top of the scroll pane from any position. Please help!

Comment: Do you want to change your JTree order ? or simply to force your JTree node to be on top of containing JScrollPane ?

Comment: There is the `scrollPathToVisible` and `scrollRootToVisible`, but they won't scroll necessarily to the top of the Scrollpane.

Comment: The order of tree nodes should not be changed. Assume the tree node at the bottom and it is some 3rd tree node, When I click to open it the previous 2 tree nodes move to up, and the clicked one should come to top on the scroll pane. I tried all the other like scrollRectToVisible(rectBounds), setRootVisible(boolean), and scrollPathToVisible(e.getPath()) kind of methods. According to Paulo, just those help to scroll the size of the tree node only, not to scroll up to top. Any help in this regard really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

As already noted: all scrollXXToVisible methods scroll such that the given XX is visible *somewhere*, they don't support finer control as f.i. "should be first node in visible area".

You have to implement that functionality yourself, something like

```
TreePath path = tree.getSelectionPath();
if (path == null) return;
Rectangle bounds = tree.getPathBounds(path);
// set the height to the visible height to force the node to top 
bounds.height = tree.getVisibleRect().height;
tree.scrollRectToVisible(bounds);
```

Beware: doing so in reaction to a mouse event on the node might be annoying to the user as it moves the target from under its feet.

Answer (score 2):

Use the scrollRectToVisible method on the actual `JTree`.

Example:

```
tree.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(0,0));
```

Comment: I tested with the new Rectangle(0,0). The complete panel is visible under tree node, but the node has not moved to top of the scroll pane.

Comment: @Mani, a SSCCE would be helpful.

Comment: Could you please explain this SSCCE? How this is helpful in this regard?

Comment: http://sscce.org/      (The website does a good job explaining how helpful it is)

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked a long time ago, and I don't know if you still need this...

I understand the problem you have, the issue is this: tree selection listeners don't work as you might expect. You have to detect the click event by registering a mouse listener. Something like this:

```
tree = new JTree();
    tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);
    MouseListener ml = new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            int selRow = tree.getRowForLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
            currentRow = selRow;
            TreePath selPath = tree.getPathForLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (selRow != -1) {
                DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(selPath.getLastPathComponent());
                if (node != null && node.isLeaf()) {
                    String stringId = '<sting-id-of-node-you-wish-to-scroll-to>';
                    TreePath tp = tree.getNextMatch(stringId, currentRow, Position.Bias.Forward);
                    if (tp == null) {
                        tp = tree.getNextMatch(stringId, currentRow, Position.Bias.Backward);
                    }
                    tree.setSelectionPath(tp);
                    tree.scrollPathToVisible(tp);
                }
            }
        }
    };
    tree.addMouseListener(ml);
```

Cheers!